# How to pass all contacts from iphone (simulator) to a table?

Tags: ios, abaddressbook

I'm a noob on IOS, and I'm trying to pass all contacts from iphone (simulator) to a table. I've followed some tutorials, but I'm getting an error.

Can you help me with that?

I've tried it:

```
#import <AddressBookUI/AddressBookUI.h>
.
.
.
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate( );
CFArrayRef allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople( addressBook );
CFIndex nPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount( addressBook );

for ( int i = 0; i < nPeople; i++ )
{
    ABRecordRef ref = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex( allPeople, i );
     NSLog(@"%@",ref);
}
```

I get this errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_ABAddressBookCreate", referenced from:
      -[younifyTableViewController viewDidLoad] in younifyTableViewController.o
  "_ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople", referenced from:
      -[younifyTableViewController viewDidLoad] in younifyTableViewController.o
  "_ABAddressBookGetPersonCount", referenced from:
      -[younifyTableViewController viewDidLoad] in younifyTableViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: what error? can we see some code? Read the #1 SO user's post about how to write questions for help: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Comment: sorry, I've edited my question now :)

Comment: Have you added the framework to your project? Just importing it in that line isn't enough.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to link your project with the AddressBook framework. In Xcode, navigate to your project settings (the top-level item in the file browser), go to the “Build Phases” tab, expand the “Link Binary With Libraries” section, click the “+” icon, select “`AddressBook.framework`,” and click OK. This should fix your problem.

The error message you see tells you that when compiling your app, it can’t find the symbols listed. These symbols are *declared* in the AddressBook headers you’ve imported, but they’re *implemented* in the framework, which is why you need to link to it. The linking process fills in these symbols.

Comment: Tks a lot man! It solved my problem. And now I know how to import libraries! ahah

Comment: And how to get your questions answered. :)